# WildFly configure JSF Context Param from CLI instead of web.xml

Tags: jsf, wildfly

I am working with WildFly 11 and JSF.

Is it possible to set the context-params `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` and `javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD` generally for all deployments on the App Server instead of the web.xml inside of the deployment? Maybe inside of the standalone-full.xml or via CLI command?

I would like to set different Values on Develpment / Test / Production Servers, independent of the web.xml inside of the deployment.

Is there any kind of overriding mechanism to override the values of the web.xml?

Comment: Yes there is. I did a google search for you ["jsf set projectstage via jndi site:stackoverflow.com"](https://www.google.com/search?q=jsf+set+projectstage+via+jndi+site:stackoverflow.com) and maybe you can state which one is the best for you so we can mark this question as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Thanx for the hint. The option 1 refers to Tomcat, is there an aequivalent in WildFly? If so, what config file exactly?

Comment: Did you read option 2,3,4,5...? And please check how to **generically** set whatever property in wildfly via JNDI... Google (or any other search engine) is, in this regard, your friend! And read the GlassFish ones too, since they contain relevant/generic info